# Wrong millimeter values for standard paper sizes at Wikipedia?

Tags: multiplicative-function

On the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size there are tables for standard paper sizes. The table "ANSI and CAN paper sizes" has paper size values expressed in `inches` and `millimeters`. For example, the `ANSI D` paper size is expressed as "22 × 34 inches" or "559 × 864 mm". But when you calculate the conversion by multiplying the `inches` values with `25.4` to get the `millimeter` values you get:

22 * 25.4 = 558.8

and:

34 * 25.4 = 863.6

So, is my calculation wrong or are the `millimeter` values on the Wikipedia page wrong? Because there is no mention about rounding on the Wikipedia page. (Assuming the ANSI paper sizes were originally defined as `inches` and then converted into `millimeters`).

Comment: Given that there are no millimeter values with decimal parts on that page, I think it's safe to assume that all values are rounded to the nearest millimeter.

Answer (score 1):

Having written a good part of said article, I can confirm that we are trying to enforce a sensible number of **significant digits**. This usually results in rounding to the nearest millimeter.

From time to time, a random user believes that conversions should be more (i.e. overly) precise and hence changes one table or the other. Such edits may go by unnoticed for a while, so the article may not always be 100% consistent. The rounding policy isn't stated in the article explicitly, because it follows from Wikipedia's [Manual of Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style#Unit_conversions)

I'm not sure whether ANSI or any other American standardization body specifies tolerances for paper sizes, but in ISO 216 and DIN 476 they are at least 1 mm and up to 3 mm for longer sides. That means, millimeter precision in conversions from inch values is arguably even *too correct*. Canadian standards rounded Letter etc. dimensions to the closest half-centimeter which might more accurately reflect actual American paper sizes.

The most common inch-based paper sizes are specified with a precision of half an inch. For other sizes, it rarely goes beyond a quarter inch, i.e. about 6 mm. Even if we assume a precision of half that for the definitions, we are still very well on the safe side in rounding converted metric values to the nearest millimeter.